# Using boolean function in solr filter query?

Tags: solr

I have a function in my solr plugin that is defined to return a true/false given some parameters. However, I don't see in any of the documentation how I can use a boolean value derived from a function to filter query results. Is what I want to do possible in solr?

Comment: Have you tried fq={!frange l=1}function? Might work, as that would only accept ranges 1 and up (and true might be interpreted as 1)

Comment: We are also facing the same problem unable to filter using true/false. Is there any other way other than `frange`?